# Linking Controls in Access 2003 Form

Tags: ms-access, forms

I created a form in access that populates a table, **TABLE1** which pulls information from different tables for example, the database is supposed to capture trouble calls that come in from different sources, there are fields like: location, division, line, date, employee, employee id, comments, etc.

On my form, the location, division, and line come from **TABLE2** (I have the location in the form of a combo box with a drop down listing all the locations); the employee and employee id come from **TABLE3** and the user inputs the date and comments.  All of this information gets saved into TABLE1 except for the division, line, and employee id because I don't need to save them into TABLE1 as I have created a query to pull all the information together.

When the user chooses **"location"** I would like the division and line fields to automatically populate on the form but not be available for the user to update (because I don't need it to be inputted into TABLE1) I just want the user to be able to see the it.

Is this possible?  Thank you.

Comment: Why are you duplicating data? Why not just create a query that presents the data, as opposed to copying it into another table?

Comment: To add to David's comment: if you take the approach he suggests, and assuming that division and line are properties of the location, then the query will take care of populating the fields when the user selects the location.  That assumption also implies that your Table2 is a table of locations.  If that's true, you're probably better off calling the table "LocationsTable" or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I really do not want to "duplicate" the data, I just want it to be "displayed" on the form for the user information.  Yes, division and line are properties of Location.  How do I create a query to do this? Please forgive my lack of experience.  I am tasked to create databases which is out of my title.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Row Source (the query) of your combobox to include Location, Division and Line (in that order).

Then, set the Control Source of your textbox where you want to display the Division to be

```
=[LocationComboBox].[Column](1)
```

and the Control Source of the textbox where you want to display the Line to be

```
=[LocationComboBox].[Column](2)
```

Change the `LocationComboBox` to match the name of your combo box.

You will probably also want to set the Enabled property of your Textboxes to False so users don't try to edit the Division and Line.

Comment: You probably want to set both Enabled=False and Locked=True. Otherwise, the textboxes will be grayed out, which implies something different. I'd also make them flat with transparent borders so they don't look like textboxes.